# Matlab functionality similar to python's __name__=='__main__'

Tags: matlab, program-entry-point

I am looking for Matlab functionality to differentiate when script is run directly or from another script.

I build a script where I declare data to work on and I use this on other scripts and functions. When I run this script directly I would like to plot these data. When I call this script from another script I don't want to have all those plots.

In python I can build a function for plottings and call this function only when `__name__=='__main__'` I can't find how to do that in Matlab.

As example:

data.m

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5]
b = sin(a)
% plot only if run directly
figure
plot(a,b)
```

analysis.m

```
data
c = a.^2
figure
plot(c)
```

When I run analysis.m I want to have only `plot(c)` but not any other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complement @tashuhka answer (i.e using [dbstack](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstack.html)), and depending if you want to keep variables in the global scope, another solution is to turn your script into function and pass optional parameter to 'analysis.m'.

```
function [] = foo(doDebugPlot)
%[
    % Check params
    if (nargin < 1), doDebugPlot = true; end

    % Code
    ...

    % Debug
    if (~doDebugPlot), return; end

    plot(lala);
    plot(tutut); 
%]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use ´dbstack´ [[1]](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/dbstack.html) to see the function calls.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is possible in MATLAB. A workaround would be to use an `if` together with [`exist`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/exist.html), like this:

analysis.m

```
run_data = 1;
data
c = a.^2
figure
plot(c)
```

data.m

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5]
b = sin(a)
% plot only if run directly
if ~exist('run_data','var')
   figure
   plot(a,b)
end
```